# If $w:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$ is a Möbius transform and $||f||_{\infty} \leq 1$, why is $||w(f(z))||_{\infty} \leq 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces, mobius-transformation

Denote the unit disk by $\mathbb{D}$. Let $w: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be a Möbius transformed defined by $w(z) = \frac{z-\lambda}{1-\overline{\lambda}z}$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{D}$ is fixed.

Suppose $f$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $||f||_{\infty} \leq 1$.

If we consider the composition $w\circ f$, I do not understand why $||w(f(z))||_{\infty} \leq 1$.

Since $w$ is bijective, and $f(z) \in \mathbb{D}$, I think $||w||_{\infty}= 1$ is the only possibility. In my mind, even if $\text{im}(f)$ is properly contained in $\mathbb{D}$, $w$ still has to map $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$. So the only least upper bound in any case is $1$.

Any clarification or insight is appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit** Since the range of $w$ is $\mathbb{D}$ and the range of the composition $w \circ f$ is contained the range of $w$, it follows that $w(f(z)) < 1.$ Therefore, the least upper bound of $|w(f(z))|$ is at most $1$; that is, $||w(f(z))||_{\infty} \leq 1$.

Comment: Consider the example $w(z) = z$. Then $\Vert w \circ f \Vert_\infty = \Vert f \Vert_\infty$, and that can be  less than one.

Comment: Geeze, I always forget to check the trivial case. Thanks for your comment! So if $\lambda \neq 0$, then $||w \circ f||_{\infty} = 1$?

Comment: No, that was only a simple example. Unless I am mistaken, $\Vert f \Vert_\infty < 1$ implies $\Vert w \circ f \Vert_\infty < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $\Vert w \circ f \Vert_\infty \le 1$ holds, but the inequality can be strict. Concretely: If
$$
\Vert f \Vert_\infty = K < 1
$$
then
$$
\Vert w \circ f \Vert_\infty \le L
$$
with 
$$
 L = \max \{ |w(z)| : |z| \le K \} < 1
$$